# New panel activating only when window resized: WxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to delete a panel ( mainPanel )and replace a panel ( secPanel )in its place. The code I have tried:

```
import wx

class secPanel ( wx.Panel ):
    def __init__ ( self, parent ):
        wx.Panel.__init__ ( self, parent = parent )
        wx.TextCtrl ( self, pos = ( 100, 100 ) )

class mainPanel ( wx.Panel ):
    def __init__ ( self, parent ):
        wx.Panel.__init__ ( self, parent = parent )
        self.parent = parent
        b = wx.Button ( self, label = "Test", pos = ( 100, 100 ) )
        self.Bind ( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onPress, b )

    def onPress ( self, event ):
        parent = self.parent
        self.Destroy()
        secPanel ( parent )
        
class Window ( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__ ( self ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent = None, title = "" )

        mainPanel ( self )
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    window = Window()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The mainPanel gets deleted but the secPanel only shows when the window is resized ( even just a pixel works ). Until I resize it shows a grey screen ( the one which would show without any panel ). This is quite annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `Layout()` is your friend.
Normally `Layout()` is used when sizers are involved but in this case, there are no sizers but the `parent` is a `wx.TopLevelWindow`.

`Layout` lays out the children using the window sizer or resizes the only child of the window to cover its entire area.

`wx.TopLevelWindow.Layout` overrides the base class Layout method to check if this window contains exactly one child – which is commonly the case, with wx.Panel being often created as the only child of wx.TopLevelWindow – and, if this is the case, resizes this child window to cover the entire client area.

See `parent.Layout()` below:

```
import wx

class secPanel ( wx.Panel ):
    def __init__ ( self, parent ):
        wx.Panel.__init__ ( self, parent = parent )
        wx.TextCtrl ( self, pos = ( 100, 100 ) )

class mainPanel ( wx.Panel ):
    def __init__ ( self, parent ):
        wx.Panel.__init__ ( self, parent = parent )
        self.parent = parent
        b = wx.Button ( self, label = "Test", pos = ( 100, 100 ) )
        self.Bind ( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onPress, b )

    def onPress ( self, event ):
        parent = self.parent
        self.Destroy()
        secPanel ( parent )
        parent.Layout()

class Window ( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__ ( self ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent = None, title = "" )

        mainPanel ( self )
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    window = Window()
    app.MainLoop()
```